# How to pass connection string to DBContext in Onion architecture application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, ninject, onion-architecture

This is a standard Onion architecture MVC application with Service and Repository layers. The application needs to read connection string from legacy component (external File source) and pass to DBContext.

How do I pass this connection string to Repository or DBContext so that it can be passed to DBContext constructor?

```
public class TSService : ITSService
{
       public TSService (ITSRepository tsRepository)
        {
        }
}
public class TSRepository : ITSRepository
{
        private IContext _context;
        public TSRepository (IContext context)
        {
            _ context = context;
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(string employeeNumber)
        {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I pass this connection string to Repository or DBContext so
>   that it can be passed to DBContext constructor?

You do this by reading the connection string from the configuration file during startup (inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)) and this is the same place where you call the `DBContext`'s constructor.

Example:

```cs
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

container.Register<DBContext>(() => new DBContext(conStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by passing the connection string. The connection string should be referenced by name, either by convention or by manually specifying it in your context definition:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
    }
}
```

Then, you define the connection string in your Web.config, using that name.

Everything else you have looks fine. You're injecting the context into your repository and your repository into your service. I will say that this *seems* like overkill. Generally, you should just have the service or the repository, three levels of dependencies seems a bit much. However, without knowing anything about your application, I can't definitely say it's "wrong"; I'd just encourage you to evaluate whether you truly need so much abstraction. Can the context simply be injected into the service and call it day?

Comment: The application needs to read connection string from legacy component where the connection string is saved in a file in custom format. So I need to know where I should call that component to read and the way to pass to upto Repository layer. As it is using DI, I do not know how it can be passed  through Repository constructor.

Comment: It needs Service later as it is doing additional logic which does not belong to domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a core service interface like ISettingService that has method to get the connection string from somewhere, and implement it in an infrastructure layer.

Pass that to your repository and then to the IContext interface that your repository is using.  Your repository should wire the two up.

Something like shown here perhaps: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rtQ81E